# Postgresql passing function name as argument to dynamically create functions

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 queries with `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, `stddev_pop()` functions. But I need a way in which I can generalize these queries into a single query with structure 
"param1(param2)".

where param1 can be MIN/MAX/AVG/stddev_pop. And param 2 can be the argument to these functions.

But I am not able to do so.

Comment: You can either have four queries in your function and use a `CASE` statement to execute the right one,, or you can use dynamic SQL. In the latter case, beware of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a wrapper

> function void(function_name, listparam, numberparam)

split params as the number is mentioned (ex:max 1 param)

inside use select case when function='selectedfunction' than call function with splitted params.